# How to create a clickable button with image over an ImageView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a beginner in iOS trying to design a small application.

I have an `UIImageView` as the Background a smaller imageView as panel.

Now I'm trying to add a button with image on the panel, but the button is not visible.

Then I remove the image and set a background color to it, the button becomes visible but not clickable.

Below is the code I wrote:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post your code as an image. Copy and paste the actual code into your question. Be sure your format it properly.

Comment: You should use storyboard. It would be better

Answer (score 0):

You can add `tapGestureRecognizer` on your `imageView` something like,

```
 let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("handleTap:"))
tap.delegate = self
BackGround.addGestureRecognizer(tap)  // your imagView
```

and can implement action method like,

```
 func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
     // do whatever you want on imageview's tap or click
}
```